# How to make a slider on background image on click?

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

I am looking for help to make a background slider on click. But so far not found any help.
This is the html section where class with section-1 is given the background:

```
<div className="section-1">
        <div className="first-button">
                <button>Enroll Now</button>
                </div>
        <i class="fa fa-angle-right scroll-button" onclick="plusSlide(-1)" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-angle-right scroll-button-left" onclick="plusSlide(1)" aria-hidden="true"></i>


        </div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
.section-1 {
    background-image: url(./assets/bg1.jpg);
    height: 75vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center; 
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
```

I also try to give it some javascript. But that javascript is only applicable in the case of simple image. I have done simple images through loop and some css classes.

Comment: This is better you place Your javascript. Also why used className instead of class?

Comment: To make it easy, I just turned here all this things to index.html. Whereas I need help in my reactjs code.

Comment: If this is a question about help with a react environment then please tag your question with react and also include the onclick code you have already.

Comment: because we don't know where is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is a reactjs topic I'll give it a try using the hover action and only css.

1. Try adding to your html a tag under your image (I used just a "p"
   tag) and give it a class of "slider".
2. Now on your .css file add:

```css
.slider {
  padding: 25vh 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  top: 6.25vh;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.2s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

> What this does basicaly is we style our paragraph to be a slider with
> it's text in the middle, and the moment we hover over it with our
> mouse the slider will appear with the text. You can edit the
> transition and the effect all you want. The basic idea is this.